# How do I render the intersection of a view and its subview?

Tags: ios, uikit, rendering

I'm currently rendering the visible part of a view to a PNG, like so:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The view has a subview called imageView (and some others); I'd like to render the visible part of the view that intersects with imageView (including the other subviews).  I'm looking at using `UIRectClip` but I get very odd results.  How do I render the intersection of a view and its subview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I needed to use `CGContextTranslateCTM`, like so:

```
CGRect combinedFrame = CGRectIntersection(imageView.frame, self.bounds);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(combinedFrame.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();    
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -combinedFrame.origin.x, -combinedFrame.origin.y);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the layer.mask property? You can mask one view using another view by saying:

```
viewA.layer.mask = viewB.layer.
```

(You'll need to #import  and add the QuartzCore framework to use these properties).